# Range Request converts to Chunked Transfer Encoding

Tags: google-app-engine

I am serving PDFs from the blobstore and I have added support for range requests.  On the first response back to the client I simply set the following headers:

resp.setHeader("X-AppEngine-BlobKey", blobkey);

resp.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

The expected behavior is that the client will receive these headers and then ask for a specific range which my app will then handle on the subsequent requests by the following:

resp.setHeader("X-AppEngine-BlobRange", range);

blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);

This works perfectly in the development environment.  Unfortunately, when it is deployed to GAE and a fast connection is being used GAE switches to Chunked Transfer Encoding and the additional request never occurs.  On slow connections it doesn't switch to chunked transfer encoding, thus working as intended.  My client for displaying the PDFs doesn't appear to support rendering the initial pages until the entire file is transferred when Chunked Transfer Encoding is used.  Thus, I would really prefer to force GAE to use range request as I have specified within the app.  Does anyone have any information on how might this be accomplished and why with fast connections it is automatically changing the expected behavior that is specified in the apps code from range request to chunked transfer encoding?

Comment: So I still haven't found a solution to the above.  I am also now storing some files on Google Cloud Storage.  Currently to serve them I simply use createGsBlobKey() and then use the same method as described above.  This results in the same issue as above.  Is there another way to serve the files through App Engine but not use the BlobStore API?